# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout and sectionHeader.pinToVisibleBounds = true

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have collection view with header sticking to top while scrolling. How can I change the colour of header text when particular section reaches to the top of collection view while user scrolling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this callback

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

Inside this function check if it's the last row of the specific section.

Hope this helps.